# Does WPF provide any built-in charting controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, charts

My .NET GUI experience is mainly with Winforms+.Net Framework, where one has [system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting?view=netframework-4.8) namespace. Moving to WPF and probably .Net Core for new projects, I cannot find an easy answer what visualization controls are actually provided as standard?

Is there a direct replacement (for Windows only)? Where in the documentation can I get a better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not easily. Nothing there, you do not overlook it.

And no, not going into recommending you one - there are plenty commercial ones or open source, for specific functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't expect recommendations. Seems disappointing they'd drop all the stuff they had in Winforms though!

Comment: Not REALLY -it is a fringe (most people do not use it) and even the one in winform had VERY limited use case. Once you want some proper charting, this standard component was falling apart extremely fast. Slow, limited functionality, no support for anything you need outside of an excel basic chart.